# Safari 16 and notifications in WebExtension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, push-notification, safari, notifications, safari-extension

I developed extension for Chrome, Edge, Opera and Firefox but now I want to convert my Chrome Extension to Safari. I know that notifications are supported from Safari 16, but is there any way to show notifications from safari extension? It looks like `chrome.notifications` or `browser.notifications` doesn't work in Safari, even on Ventura Beta.

Can someone confirm that it doesn't work in Safari?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I have the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75660781/can-macos-safari-web-extensions-issue-local-notifications-without-asking-for-per).

Comment: @RobHawkins notifications in Safari doesn't work in extensions :(