# Can MacOS Safari Web Extensions issue local notifications without asking for permission twice?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, safari-web-extension

I'm attempting to convert an extension from Chrome/Firefox to Safari. Having followed instructions [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/safari_web_extensions/converting_a_web_extension_for_safari), everything seems to work except for notifications.

`chrome.notifications` is undefined in Safari, both for manifest v2 and v3. In a v3 extension's service worker, `Notification` (the API for web workers) is accessible, though that requires that I [request permission](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notifications_API/Using_the_Notifications_API#getting_permission) to use it. I can see how that makes sense for a web worker. I don't think it makes sense for an extension whose permissions were already approved before installation. But, maybe these are different APIs meant for different tasks, and Safari simply has not or does not plan to implement [`browser.notifications`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/notifications#browser_compatibility).

Basically, in order to use `registration.showNotification` in a web extension for Safari, it seems I need to request additional permission from the user via a gesture. That means they need to install the extension and then separately activate that preference on their own. Do I have that right?

Answer (score 0):

Safari (17.1, at the time of writing this answer) still does not support any form of push or local notifications inside Safari Web/App Extensions.

Although Safari 16 has introduced the relevant Notifications API (including Web Push API), it is available only for regular websites, and not for Safari Web/App extensions. The legacy Safari Push Notifications are also available only for regular websites and not for extensions.